# MACHINE_CHECK_EXCEPTION, Windows7

Tags: windows-7, cpu

3 year old Notebook HP Pavilion dv7 is displaying an error which is:

> ### MACHINE_CHECK_EXCEPTION
>
> STOP: 0x0000009C (0x0000000000000000, 0xFFFFF880009F1C70,
>   0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000)

I did some research on google and such and i know it is CPU or Power Supply  but no further info or how to resolve the problem.

- Spec:
- CPU: Intel Core i7 Q720@1.60Ghz - NO OC
- GPU: ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5650
- 8GB RAM
- WIN7 HE 64x

Loaded BIOS defaults - error still appearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This generally means a hardware failure - though issues with the BIOS/UEFI can cause this.

- Make sure your system is well ventilated and dusted.
- Open your system up and make sure all fans are working.
- Check the power needs of your GPU and make sure your power supply is rated to handle.

Next:

- Update BIOS/system firmware to latest version.
- Swap out RAM modules and try to isolate to see if this occurs with only one installed.  If it does, that module may be bad.
- Replace your power supply if it's possible, particularly if you are using an OEM one.
- The GPU itself may be faulty and causing this.
- If it still occurs, you may have a bad motherboard or CPU.